# Objeto deletado sendo retornado num fetch do Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Estou com um "pequeno" problema ao usar o Core Data.

Esta é a minha arquitetura:

Synchronizer -> SyncService -> PersistenceService -> NSManagedObject

Todas as classes na camada do PersistenceService herdam esta estrutura:

```
# PersistenceService.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface PersistenceService : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *context;

-(instancetype) init;
-(void) saveContext;
@end

# PersistenceService.m
@implementation PersistenceService

-(instancetype) init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        self.context.parentContext = [DataManager sharedInstance].managedObjectContext;
    }

    return self;
}

-(void) saveContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.context.parentContext;

    [self.context performBlock:^{

        NSError *error;
        [self.context save:&error];

        [context performBlock:^{
            NSError *error;
            [context save:&error];

            [context.parentContext performBlock:^{
                NSError *error;
                [context.parentContext save:&error];

            }];
        }];
    }];

}

@end
```

No início do ciclo de execução, meu Synchronizer faz um fetch dos objetos que vou precisar e passo para o SyncService operar sobre eles. Sempre utilizo o `parentContext` para qualquer coisa que não seja alterar (criar, editar, salvar, deletar) os próprios objetos:

```
# Synchronizer.m
-(void) synchronize {
    NSArray *pseudoLeads = [[[PseudoLeadPersistenceService alloc] init] getAllParentPseudoLeads];
    if (pseudoLeads) {
        PseudoLeadDAO *pseudoLead = [pseudoLeads objectAtIndex:0];
        if ([pseudoLead.type isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:Capture]]) {
            CaptureSyncService *service = [[CaptureSyncService alloc] initWithDelegate:self andPseudoLead:pseudoLead];
            [service executeRequest];
        } else {
            HotleadSyncService *service = [[HotleadSyncService alloc] initWithDelegate:self andPseudoLead:pseudoLead];
            [service executeRequest];
        }
    }
}
```

Após o SyncService terminar de realizar suas operações, preciso deletar o objeto para que ele saia da fila e os próximos sejam tratados. Abaixo segue o código que uso para recuperar o objeto que desejo deletar no `context` normal e onde faço o delete de fato:

```
# PseudoLeadPersistenceService.m
-(void) deletePseudoLeadById:(NSNumber *)pseudoLeadId andEventId:(NSNumber *)eventId {
    PseudoLeadDAO *pseudoLeadDAO = [PseudoLeadDAO findPseudoLeadById:pseudoLeadId andEventId:eventId inContext:self.context];
    [self.context deleteObject:pseudoLeadDAO];
    [self saveContext];
}
```

Depois disso o processo se inicia de novo no Synchronizer (ou deveria). O problema, é que ao voltar pro método `-(void) synchronize` e fazer o fetch, o objeto que acabou de ser deletado está sendo retornado novamente. Não importa quantos fetchs eu faça nesse ponto, ele sempre vem. O processo continua e só para quando o objeto chega novamente no método de deleção, que é quando ao tentar acessar as propriedades do objeto nil é retornado e faz com que o programa quebre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema era a concorrência. A thread criada salvar os contextos não estava finalizando antes de ocorrer o próximo fetch.

Resolvi o problema adicionando o seguinte método ao PersistenceService.

```
# PersistenceService.m
-(void) saveContextAndWait {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.context.parentContext;

    [self.context performBlockAndWait:^{

        NSError *error;
        [self.context save:&error];

        [context performBlockAndWait:^{
            NSError *error;
            [context save:&error];

            [context.parentContext performBlockAndWait:^{
                NSError *error;
                [context.parentContext save:&error];

            }];
        }];
    }];
}
```

Agora o método que deleta o objeto chama este novo:

```
# PseudoLeadPersistenceService.m
-(void) deletePseudoLeadById:(NSNumber *)pseudoLeadId andEventId:(NSNumber *)eventId {
    PseudoLeadDAO *pseudoLeadDAO = [PseudoLeadDAO findPseudoLeadById:pseudoLeadId andEventId:eventId inContext:self.context];
    [self.context deleteObject:pseudoLeadDAO];
    [self saveContextAndWait];
}
```